# Generating AlephOne-style visualizations of the stack?

Tags: c, x86, stack, static-analysis, buffer-overflow

In the widely-read "[Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit](http://www.phrack.com/issues.html?issue=49&id=14)" tutorial, Aleph One presents C code examples like this:

```
void function(int a, int b, int c) {
    char buffer1[5];
    char buffer2[10];
}

void main() {
    function(1,2,3);
}
```

Then, based on some intuition (and sometimes peeking at the X86 assembly), Aleph One produces diagrams of the stack configuration. For example, the stack of `function(int a, int b, int c)` looks like this:

```
bottom of                                                            top of
memory                                                               memory
           buffer2       buffer1   sfp   ret   a     b     c
<------   [            ][        ][    ][    ][    ][    ][    ]

top of                                                            bottom of
stack                                                                 stack
```

After reading the tutorial and practicing a bit, I'm now able to produce diagrams like the one above by hand. However, producing these diagrams by hand can be a bit tedious for programs that are more complex.

**Is there a tool that can generate stack diagrams like this, perhaps by doing static analysis?**

Comment: I think using the `clang` library, you can easily write a small tool for this task.

Comment: How is such a diagram useful outside the context of "explain how the stack works"? There may be a tool which satisfies the use you have for this diagram.

Comment: @DavidMorris I'm self-studying some computer security stuff. These visualizations are useful for figuring out where the `ret` variable is when you want to overwrite `ret` with a buffer overflow.